# Android app doesn't have name completion

Tags: feature-request, android-app, comment-replies

I tried to reply to a person who posted a comment on my question, but the `@name` syntax didn't put a list of names for me to choose, requiring me to have to type the entire name in.  This is annoying, esp when there are names that are long and have no resemblance to any word in my phone keyboard dictionary and may add these to my dictionary if typed in fully myself.

Answer (score 3):

Not a bug and you don't need that feature to begin with. When you tap a comment, you get a reply button:

> [image]

Tapping it will automagically put `@` followed by the comment's author name in the comment textbox.

We can start feature request asking for autocomplete as well, but personally don't see any need when there is a reply icon.

Comment: That's cool. but there are those times that I don't want it at the beginning and I may have already started typing.

Comment: Feel free to start such feature request, but chances for this to be done are really slim, in my opinion.